# Is "optimization to" correct phrasing?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

I have this sentence in my bachelor's thesis:

> *After a paragraph describing an accommodation subprocess (set of activities)...*
>
> **Basically, there are two potential optimizations to this subprocess.**
>
> *...then a paragraph describing two possible optimizations.*

Is it correct to use *optimization to* in this context? I didn't find any similar expression on the web.

Comment: There are quite a few usage references on web:
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22potential+optimizations+to%22&oq=%22potential+optimizations+to%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.820&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

In your context, usage seems fine to me!

Comment: What is that sentence describing? Perhaps *optimisations of* might be better, indicating that the subprocess might optimised in either (or even both) of two different ways.

Comment: Preceding paragraph describes an accommodation subprocess (set of activities) and succeeding paragraph describes two possible optimizations. I cite from my bachelor's thesis.

Comment: Even after the bolded sentence, you still refer to "two possible optimizations" -- a potential ambiguity. You are not stating categorically whether you are referring to **two ways of optimization** or **two optimized solutions (results)**. You will need to rephrase to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d put it differently altogether. If I understand the concept correctly, something like *There are two ways in which this sub-process can be implemented* might be clearer. But, as always, it depends on who your readers are.

Comment: Your interpretation seems to be wrong in meaning as compared to OP's. 
There is a "subprocess" which has two "potential" optimizations. Those two optimizations may or may not be implemented. It gives a non-definite connotation. Your interpretation tries to give it a near-to-definite connotation.

Comment: It sounds like the computing equivalent of psychobabble to me. Still, I suppose it means something to somebody.

Comment: I think I know what you are saying. Maybe you went by the literal interpretation of the OP's sentence.

Comment: What does OP mean? My readers will be a state exam jury educated in IT science. I described the context more in detail in comments above.

Comment: @Andrew. OP = Original Poster. That's you.

Comment: I think OP's construction is inherently ambiguous, and also that it's slightly odd phrasing to start with. Personally I'd be likely to say *"There are two ways this sub-process can be optimised"*. I realise that's still potentially ambiguous, but to me it would imply *only one or the other can be applied*. If I wanted to more strongly imply that ***both*** optimisations could be applied, I'd probably say *"There are two optimisations which can be applied to this sub-process"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for rephrasing the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Given that the following paragraph goes on to describe *two* possible optimisations, the correct word to use would be *of* rather than *to* which would be appropriate if there was only *one*  possible optimisation.

Your sentence should therefore read –

> Basically, there are two potential optimizations of this subprocess.

Comment: -1: I don't think the choice of preposition (which can validly be *"to"*, *"of"*, or *"for"*) has any bearing on whether there are one or more potential optimisations, or whether those optimisations are mutually exclusive alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

In OP's exact construction, the choice of preposition is effectively arbitrary. It can validly be *"to", "of"*, or *"for"* - all of which are used by competent speakers.

That choice is *not* affected by whether there's one or more potential optimisations, nor does it affect the inherent ambiguity over whether those optimisations are mutually exclusive alternatives or not.

With the phrasing as given, I personally would make no assumption regarding that ambiguity. It's inherent in many constructions referring to *[more than one] different way[s] to improve [something]*, whatever the precise wording. You need completely different phrasing to distinguish...

> Either or both of two optimisations could be applied to this subprocess.

...from...

> This subprocess can be optimised in one of two different ways.

---

FWIW, here are some usage figures from Google Books...

> *optimizations [of the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22usen%27t%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22optimizations%20of%20the%22&oq=%22optimizations%20of%20the%22&gs_l=serp.3...11562.12241.15.12871.2.2.0.0.0.0.188.259.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.MYxgPKdR__4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) (14,200); [for the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22usen%27t%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22optimizations%20for%20the%22&oq=%22optimizations%20for%20the%22&gs_l=serp.3...3310.4773.17.5074.5.5.0.0.0.0.81.326.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.hQmjR37jICQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) (5020); [to the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22usen%27t%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22optimizations%20to%20the%22&oq=%22optimizations%20to%20the%22&gs_l=serp.3...34185.34991.16.36317.3.3.0.0.0.0.72.186.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.oHmT4CasG_w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) (3840).*
>
> *optimisations [of the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22usen%27t%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22optimisations%20of%20the%22&oq=%22optimisations%20of%20the%22&gs_l=serp.3...4741.8919.9.9598.14.14.0.0.0.0.81.634.14.14.0...0.0...1c.1.meS8Ugi5TTU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) (1,100); [for the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22usen%27t%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22optimisations%20for%20the%22&oq=%22optimisations%20for%20the%22&gs_l=serp.3...296034.298854.18.299847.9.7.2.0.0.1.127.419.6j1.7.0...0.0...1c.1.UgAFuTubwFI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) (194); [to the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22usen%27t%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22optimisations%20to%20the%22&oq=%22optimisations%20to%20the%22&gs_l=serp.3...26399.27845.19.28116.5.5.0.0.0.0.63.266.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.3fgsWAmLREQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) (156).*